# Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js)

Tags: angular

In architectectui angular 12 theme, I get this below message if I run ng serve:
TypeError: Cannot create property 'message' on string 'C:\The Soft Africa\ArchitectUI Angular\architectui-angular-pro-4.0.0\node_modules\ng-apexcharts\fesm2015\ng-apexcharts.mjs: This application depends upon a library published using Angular version 15.2.9, which requires Angular version 14.0.0 or newer to work correctly.
Consider upgrading your application to use a more recent version of Angular.
Can someone help me with solution?[this is the console I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrhKj.png)
below is the content of my package.json file:

{
"name": "architectui-angular-pro",
"version": "4.0.0",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e",
"postinstall": "ngcc"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
"@angular-redux/store": "^9.0.0",
"@angular/animations": "^12.1.3",
"@angular/cdk": "^12.1.3",
"@angular/common": "^12.1.3",
"@angular/compiler": "^12.1.3",
"@angular/core": "^12.1.3",
"@angular/forms": "^12.1.3",
"@angular/google-maps": "^11.0.3",
"@angular/localize": "^12.1.3",
"@angular/material": "^12.1.3",
"@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^12.1.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^12.1.3",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.1.3",
"@angular/router": "^12.1.3",
"@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.8.1",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.32",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
"@kolkov/angular-editor": "^1.1.4",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^11.0.0-beta.2",
"@ng-select/ng-select": "^5.0.15",
"@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^5.1.1",
"@ngx-loading-bar/router": "^5.1.1",
"@ngx-progressbar/core": "^5.3.2",
"@ngx-progressbar/http": "^5.3.2",
"@ngxs/store": "^3.7.1",
"@popperjs/core": "^2.9.2",
"angular-calendar": "^0.28.22",
"angular-gauge": "^4.0.0",
"angular-svg-round-progressbar": "^5.0.2",
"angular2-ladda": "^3.1.1",
"animate-sass": "^0.8.2",
"apexcharts": "^3.23.1",
"bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
"chart.js": "^2.9.4",
"chartjs-adapter-luxon": "^0.2.2",
"chartjs-plugin-annotation": "^0.5.7",
"chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^0.7.0",
"core-js": "^3.8.2",
"date-fns": "^2.16.1",
"flag-icon-css": "^3.5.0",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"ionicons": "^4.6.3",
"ionicons-npm": "^2.0.1",
"jquery": "^3.5.1",
"jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2": "^2.0.5",
"ladda": "^2.0.1",
"linearicons": "^1.0.2",
"loaders.css": "^0.1.2",
"lodash-es": "^4.17.20",
"luxon": "^1.25.0",
"ng-apexcharts": "^1.5.6",
"ng-bootstrap-form-validation": "^9.0.0",
"ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.14",
"ng2-archwizard": "^2.1.0",
"ng2-charts": "^2.4.2",
"ng2-nouislider": "^1.8.2",
"ngx-clipboard": "^14.0.1",
"ngx-color-picker": "^11.0.0",
"ngx-countup": "^7.3.3",
"ngx-dropzone-wrapper": "^10.0.1",
"ngx-image-cropper": "^3.3.3",
"ngx-loading": "^8.0.0",
"ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^10.1.0",
"ngx-progressbar": "^6.1.0",
"ngx-select-dropdown": "^1.4.4",
"ngx-slick-carousel": "^0.5.1",
"ngx-textarea-autosize": "^2.0.3",
"ngx-toastr": "^13.2.0",
"ngx-trend": "^6.1.1",
"nouislider": "^14.6.3",
"pe7-icon": "^1.0.4",
"popper.js": "^1.16.0",
"redux": "4.0.0",
"rxjs": "^6.6.3",
"slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
"sweetalert2": "^10.13.0",
"tslib": "^2.1.0",
"zone.js": "~0.11.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.1.3",
"@angular/cli": "^12.1.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.1.3",
"@angular/language-service": "^12.1.3",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.11.2",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/node": "^12.11.1",
"codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
"cross-env": "^5.2.1",
"increase-memory-limit": "^1.0.7",
"jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
"karma": "^6.3.2",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
"karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
"protractor": "~7.0.0",
"redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
"sass": "^1.32.4",
"ts-node": "~7.0.0",
"tslint": "~6.1.0",
"typescript": "~4.3.5"
}
}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.